# memory leak in adding and deleting dynamic list

Tags: c, list, memory, allocation

I really need your help in this matter. I have these two functions that do the following:

1. copy face struct and add it to a list of faces (_face_list_entry_t)
2. copy a pointer of struct and add it to a list of pointers (fib_entry_t )

I created these two functions to dynamically allocate and add new items (faces and pointers) to their respected list. (I don't want the function of removing item)

I am currently facing a memory leak and I am not sure if allocating/reallocating/freeing the memory in them causes this issue. Below is the the two functions:

```
int8_t face_list_add(_face_list_entry_t** face_list, int8_t* face_list_size, _face_list_entry_t* face)
{
    if (*face_list == NULL) {
        *face_list = malloc(sizeof(_face_list_entry_t));

        if (*face_list == NULL) {
            DEBUG("fail to allocate memory for face list\n");
            return -1;
        }

        *face_list_size = 1;
        (*face_list)[0].id   = face->id;
        (*face_list)[0].type = face->type;

        return 0;

    } else {
        // check for existing face entry
        for (int i = 0; i < *face_list_size; ++i) {
            if ((*face_list)[i].id == face->id) {
                DEBUG("wildcard: same face exists in the fib entry\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // need to add a new entry to the face list
        _face_list_entry_t *list = (_face_list_entry_t*) realloc( *face_list, (*face_list_size + 1) * sizeof(_face_list_entry_t));
        DEBUG("facelist size = %d\n", (*face_list_size + 1) * sizeof(_face_list_entry_t));
        if (list == NULL) {
            DEBUG("fail to reallocate memory for face list (size=%d)\n", *face_list_size);
            return -1;
        }
        *face_list = list;
        (*face_list)[*face_list_size].id = face->id;
        (*face_list)[*face_list_size].type = face->type;
        ++(*face_list_size);
        return 0;
    }
}

int8_t pointer_list_add(fib_entry_t ***fib_list, int8_t *fib_list_size, fib_entry_t **fib)
{
    if (*fib_list == NULL) {
        *fib_list = malloc(sizeof(fib_entry_t *));
        if (!*fib_list) {
            DEBUG("fail to allocate memory for fib list\n");
            return -1;
        }
        *fib_list_size = 1;
        **fib_list = *fib;
        return 0;
    } else {
        // check for existing fib entry
        for (int i = 0; i < *fib_list_size; ++i) {
            if ((*fib_list)[i] == *fib) {
                DEBUG("same fib exists in the fib entry\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        // need to add a new entry to the fib list
        fib_entry_t **list = (fib_entry_t **)realloc(*fib_list, (*fib_list_size + 1) * sizeof(fib_entry_t *));
        if (!list) {
            DEBUG("fail to reallocate memory for fib list (size=%d)\n", *fib_list_size);
            return -1;
        }
        **fib_list = *list;
        (*fib_list)[*fib_list_size] = *fib;
        ++(*fib_list_size);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I call them like this:

```
res = face_list_add(&list_faces, &lst_faces_size, face);
res = pointer_list_add(&list_fibs, &list_fibs_size, &fib);
```

I delete the list like below. I don't want to delete the memory that each pointer is pointing to, I just want to delete the allocated memory for the list of pointers and the list of faces:

```
free(list_faces);
free(list_fibs);
```

Please let me know if I am doing it wrong or suggest a better way (low cost) as the device I am working on has a constrained capability, very low memory (256KB), and low process power, i.e. maintaining memory is crucial. Besides, usually, both lists are relatively small but in some cases can become bigger.

Your help is highly appreciated

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak?

Comment: the program cannot allocate memory anymore after a while

Comment: When you suspect a memory leak (if not before) is the time to roll out an appropriate diagnostic tool, such as Valgrind.  Not only will such tools confirm or deny your suspicion, they will also help you determine what memory is being leaked.

Comment: will this tool works with RIOT-OS and TI CC2538 devices, I am afraid I don't have the debugging tool for now and I am not sure if it will work with Valgrind. All I have got is printing to screen

Comment: @Ahed, it would not be too much trouble to unit test (just) the code presented on a system that Valgrind supports.

Comment: I tried it and it was nice... it shows the error I had, i.e., the one mentioned in your answer. At least I can check some parts/functions with it, thanks for the recommendation, @JohnBollinger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `face_list_add()` and `pointer_list_add()` functions presented and these calls that (re)allocate memory ...

> ```
> res = face_list_add(&list_faces, &lst_faces_size, face);
> res = pointer_list_add(&list_fibs, &list_fibs_size, &fib);
> ```

, these `free()` calls ...

> ```
> free(list_faces);
> free(list_fibs);
> ```

... are correct for for freeing the memory allocated by those functions.  Or they would be, if the functions were correct.  `face_list_add()` appears to be ok, but there is an error in realloc branch of `pointer_list_add()`, here:

> ```
>         **fib_list = *list;
> ```

That should be

```
        *fib_list = list;
```

, analogous to

> ```
>         *fib_list = malloc(sizeof(fib_entry_t *));
> ```

in the initial allocation branch.

Comment: I have initially defined the fib and face list like this: fib_entry_t* list_fibs=NULL; _face_list_entry_t* face =NULL; before I use the calling function, I still can't understand why I should use  *fib_list = list; instead. do you think this might cause the leak issue?

Comment: @Ahed, it should be `*fib_list = list` for the same reason that it is (as it should be) `*fib_list = malloc(sizeof(fib_entry_t *))`.  In each case, `fib_list` is (presumably) a pointer to a variable belonging to the caller, which points to the allocated space.  When you allocate or reallocate such space, it is therefore to `*fib_list` that the resulting pointer must be assigned.  `**fib_list` is the wrong level of indirection, and it is in fact invalid after `*fib_list` is the subject of a `realloc()`.

Comment: And that is a serious error.  It is not only possible but likely that it results in leaked memory and / or corrupted memory allocation metadata, either of which could cause allocations to fail.  Again, Valgrind or a similar tool would give you more information.

Comment: I got it now, thanks for clearing that up... Valgrind shows that too, I appreciate your help